# Changing font of strings separated by spaces

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to make the words split by spaces green in a UITextField, kind of like the way it works when you compose of a new iMessage. I commented out the part of my code that's giving me a runtime error. Please let me know if you have any ideas:

```
func textChanged(sender : UITextField) {

    var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    let arr = sender.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    var c = 0

    for i in arr {

        /*

        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location:c,length:i.characters.count))

        sender.attributedText = myMutableString

        */

        print(c,i.characters.count)

        c += i.characters.count + 1

    }

}
```

Comment: You should really tell your readers the specific runtime error that you're getting. It can be hard to figure out what is wrong with code just by looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has at least two parts needed to be fixed.

```
var myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
```

This line creates an empty `NSMutableAttributedString`. Any access to the content may cause runtime error.

The other is `i.characters.count`. You should not use `Character` based locations and counts, when the APIs you want use is based on the behaviour of `NSString`. Use UTF-16 based count.

And one more, this is not critical, but you should use sort of meaningful names for variables.

So, all included:

```
func textChanged(sender: UITextField) {
    let text = sender.text ?? ""
    let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let components = text.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    var currentPosition = 0
    for component in components {
        myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location: currentPosition,length: component.utf16.count))
        sender.attributedText = myMutableString

        print(currentPosition, component.utf16.count)
        currentPosition += component.utf16.count + 1
    }
}
```

But whether this works as you expect or not depends on when this method is called.

Comment: I'm currently calling it from `textField.addTarget(self, action: "textChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)`. This just makes all the text green all the time... What do you suggest?

Comment: Added an if statement to remove the word that's currently being written and it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Happy to hear that you have solved your issue. Good luck for you and for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty attributed string but never install any text into it.

The `addAttribute` call apples attributes to text in a string. If you try to apply attributes to a range that does not contain text, you will crash.

You need to install the content of the unattributed string into the attributed string, then apply attributes.

Note that you should probably move the line

```
sender.attributedText = myMutableString
```

Outside of your for loop. There is no good reason to install the attributed string to the text field repeatedly as you add color attributes to each word.

Note this bit from the Xcode docs on `addAttribute`:

> Raises... an NSRangeException if any part of aRange lies beyond the
>   end of the receiver’s characters.

If you are getting an `NSRangeException` that would be a clue as to what is wrong with your current code. Pay careful attention to the error messages you get. They usually offer important clues as to what's going wrong.